# TinyMCE: добавить атрибут title в элемент a(ссылку)?

Tags: tinymce

Добрый день, возможно ли в TinyMCE добавить к ссылке атрибут title?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

тебе придется менять плагин link на вот этот фикс https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/pull/234
стандартными способами добавить поле title туда нельзя